# How to set title of Terminal in Linux Mint 18

Tags: linux-mint, gnome-terminal, menu

I upgraded to Linux Mint 18; everything went well. I don't know if it was intentionally done like this or not, but the option `Terminal -> Set Title` is no longer there, and the shortcut is no longer available. Why this change has been made, and how to fix it? I need to set terminal title, because it helps me navigate between tabs quickly.

Comment: Which terminal emulator are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Use bash internals:

```
 PS1="\033]0;New Title\007"$PS1
```